# Как настроить <select> в моей форме?

Tags: php, html, laravel

> у меня есть форма я сделал ее селект она рабочая но когда я захожу
>   снова регистрировать пользователя у меня выходит самая первая в теге
>    а мне нужно чтобы выходило значение пользователя .Допустим я зашел в бил оператор сохранился в бд все хорошо ну когда я повторно захожу редактировать у меня опять пользователь хоть в бд сохранение оператор

***вот форма***

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{Form::Label('rank','Должность')}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10"  >
            <select {{Form::text('rank', null,['class'=>'form-control'])}} >
                <option value="пользователь">пользователь</option>
                <option value="оператор">оператор</option>
                <option value="админ">админ</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: дополнительно в бд занести ступени 1 2 или 3 при загрузке страницы будет проверка на какую стадию вывести

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого надо прописать атрибут `selected` для `option`.

Допустим есть роль пользователя в переменной - `$user_role = 'оператор';`

```
<option {{ $user_role == 'пользователь' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="пользователь">пользователь</option>
<option {{ $user_role == 'оператор' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="оператор">оператор</option>
<option {{ $user_role == 'админ' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="админ">админ</option>
```

В таком случае активным будет именно вариант где `$user_role == 'админ'`

[Документация атрибута selected](http://htmlbook.ru/html/option/selected)

**UPD:**

Допустим мы здесь сохраняем пользователя в базу данных:

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    // записываем последний выбранный ранк пользователя в сессию
    $request->session()->put('rank', $request->rank);

    // ....
}
```

После в шаблоне делаем проверку

```
<option {{ session('rank') == 'пользователь' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="пользователь">пользователь</option>
```

и также аналогично для других

Comment: все равно если зайти опять в редактирование будет пользователь в поле указан а должен быть тот который был указан в последний раз